# How to write it in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing the following in LINQ

```
Enumerable.Range(50, 100).Select(n => n/10 == 1)
```

but it's not working. How to write the above query?

Comment: You'll have to provide more code and the actual error you're getting.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you expect and what does not work?

Comment: You should say HOW it isn't working. Is it failing to compile? Or is it returning nothing? Or is it returning everything? Or is it crashing? You need to give us more information!

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that the query is meant to do? From what you've posted so far it appears to be a function that takes an IEnumerable<int> and returns an IEnumerable<bool>, where the return elements are true only if the input is equal to 10 and 10 only.

Comment: I get the error Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: LOL - you do have to love StackOverflow! Four comments within two minutes asking for clarification!

Comment: I use it with Enumerable.Range(50, 100).Select(n => n/10 == 1)

Comment: Your select statement has the signature Select<int, bool>(Func<int, bool> selector) as the expression "n/10 == 1" returns a "bool". If you're trying to return an "int" then you need to explain what are you trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the values divisible by 10?

Comment: yes i am getting all value divisible by 10 between 50 and 100

Comment: That will return IEnumerable<bool> where all the values are false... If you were to use a Where statement it would return an empty enumerator.  What are you trying to get?

Comment: Could you paste your entire line of code?  Including the variable assignment (and if on a different line the variable instancing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the number from 50 to 100 that are divisible by 10 then you need this...

```
var res =  Enumerable.Range(50, 51).Where(n=>n%10==0);
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Next time you may try to provide an entire line of code and what you expect.  It may save on the confusion.

Comment: yes I will remember that and paste entire code. Sorry everyone for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Since your expression is a predicate -- and from your comment you want to return it into an `IEnumerable<int>` -- I'm guessing you actually want to filter the source collection rather than project it into a sequence of booleans.  If that's correct, you need the Where operator rather than Select:

```
var intsBetween10And19 = ints.Where(n => (n/10 == 1));
```

Select performs a projection, i.e. it "returns" the value of the select expression (in this case a boolean).  Where is the filtering operator.

Comment: +1. The `Select` operator would just then select `IEnumerable<bool>` containing whether or not each element fit the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get all of the values divisible by 10 (as per your comment) you need this:

```
Enumerable.Range(50, 100).Select(n => n % 10 == 0)
```

Comment: this is correct if you just want a set of bools... if you want the int values look at my result (by the way his range is 50 to 100 so it should be 50,51)